# ViewController has no initialisers?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2, segue

Im trying to access a enum from a model class to write a switch case to perform a segue. Here is my code:

```
class LandingViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Private Structs.

private struct SegueIdentifier {
    static let forcedUpdate = "forcedUpdate"
    static let optionalUpdate = "optionalUpdate"
}


// MARK: Private variables.

private let updateType: StartupManager.UpdateType

// MARK: LifeCycle Methods.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    StartupManager.setupForLanding()

    var segueIdentifier: String
    switch updateType {
    case .ForcedUpdate: segueIdentifier = SegueIdentifier.forcedUpdate
    case .OptionalUpdate: segueIdentifier = SegueIdentifier.optionalUpdate
    }
    performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier, sender: nil)
}
```

The `setupForLanding()` is used to check the startUpManager model class to see which of the enums is triggered.

```
class StartupManager: NSObject {

enum UpdateType {
    case OptionalUpdate
    case ForcedUpdate
}
// code to perform a check
if isForceUpdate {
   completion(.ForcedUpdate)
} else {
   completion(.OptionalUpdate)
}
```

But I keep getting an error that reads `LandingViewController has no initialisers`. How do I check in the start up manager which case is called and then perform the segue in the landingViewController?

Comment: As Thien Liu points out, the problem is that `updateType` doesn't have a default type. Either have it default to some value (or make it an optional). But, as aside, you may not want to perform a segue in `viewDidLoad`. You may want to defer this until later in the process, such as `viewDidAppear`. Depending upon how you're transitioning to this scene, you might get an error about initiating a transition in the middle of another transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize value for **updateType**

private let updateType: StartupManager.UpdateType = .OptionalUpdate for example

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here: `private let updateType: StartupManager.UpdateType`
. In swift all values should be initialised before you can use them. For that you should initialise it in constructor (init) or assign value like: `private let updateType: StartupManager.UpdateType = value`, or use optional values.

Best regards.